# Grails installation doesn't compiles neither runs a simple first step

Tags: grails

I've installed grails in OS X 10.9.5.
I runned "grails create-app elshuck".
Then I run "grails run-app", INSIDE the created directory...but frozes here:

> Lorien:elshuck hernanezequielmartinez$ sudo grails run-app
>
> Password:
>
> :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
>
> :compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
>
> :processResources
>
> :classes
>
> :findMainClass
>
> :bootRun
>
> objc[635]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both 
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
>   and
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib.
>   One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
>
> Grails application running at http://localhost:8080 in environment:
>   development
>
> Building 83% > :bootRun

What is wrong? grails version is 3.0.2.

Thanks in advance for your help, people.

Comment: See https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/641.

Comment: Why is it that you want to run `grails` under `sudo`?

Comment: For granting it administrator rights, otherwise it requires some kind of permission, like: "I do not have access to this or that"...I do not remember the precise message.

Comment: Ok, I've read the github thread. But not solutions were exposed...do you know if this is a WKB?

Comment: "do you know if this is a WKB" - What does WKB stand for?

Comment: "For granting it administrator rights, otherwise it requires some kind of permission" - You probably don't really want to be opening up http ports on your machine from a superuser process.  There isn't anything in Grails itself that requires that.  It may be that you have something else going on on your machine that is factoring in here. I recommend fixing that instead of running grails as superuser.  Just 2 cents.

Comment: "Ok, I've read the github thread. But not solutions were exposed" - See the latest comments on the thread for more info but the message there is coming from Spring Boot.  It is a nuisance, but not really that big of a deal.  The process is running and the app is accessible at the url mentioned in the output.  The "83%" is just misleading.  Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: WKB: Well Known Bug. ^_^

Comment: Thanks by the way. I see you eye to eye about sudo; do not worry. This is my very first touch of grails. I just wanted to make it run, sumehow. Later, I'll research a little why if does requires me for certain types of grants. From your point of view, which might it be so?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is fixed by https://github.com/grails/grails-profile-repository/commit/aba2e52cae255615519735f8eda90c93654897fd which should be included in the next release.

Thanks for the feedback.